# LINQ: Get attribute with any namespace but specific name

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmpp

I need to be able get a single specific attribute from an element with a specific local name but any namespace (if you are familiar with XMPP you will understand why). Apart from writing my own (enumerator or single select) extension methods, any ideas?

I have the following, but I don't like it at all:

```
        XAttribute from = (from c in elem.Attributes()
                           where c.Name.LocalName == "from"
                           select c).FirstOrDefault<XAttribute>();

        XAttribute to = (from c in elem.Attributes()
                         where c.Name.LocalName == "to"
                         select c).FirstOrDefault<XAttribute>();
```

edit: would like something like:

```
        string val = (string)elem.Attribute("{*}to");
```

solution:

```
        XAttribute from = elem.Attributes()
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName == "from");

        XAttribute to = elem.Attributes()
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName == "to");
```

Comment: Aren't most of the attributes in XMPP in the null namespace?  We hardly ever prefix, and they don't automatically pick up the namespace of the element they are on.

Comment: @Joe, the main problem I have is "jabber:server", "jabber:client" and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't like the syntax, you can use this one;

```
elem.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a=>a.Name.LocalName == "from");
```

Comment: by the way, for completeness, it should be a=>a.Name.LocalName == "from".

Comment: +1. Query expressions are nice when they're doing complicated things, but when there are just one or two operations, the "dot notation" is indeed simpler.